# History of Hindman's Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, math-history, filters, ramsey-theory

At [this blogpost](http://boolesrings.org/krautzberger/2011/08/25/hindman%E2%80%99s-theorem-partial-semigroups-and-some-of-my-most-lacking-intuitions-part-3/) about [Hindman's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_set#Hindman.27s_Theorem), I read the following lines:

> 'I love the odd history so allow me to digress... etc. '

This sentence made me curious to know what this history looks like. Someone told me Hindman himself has written a paper about it, but I could not find it. So, can anyone tell me about this history, or recommend some books / papers?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The paragraph you cite tells the history. what precisely do you mean?

Comment: It tells the history, but it is quite short. I was looking for something more extensive (like I said, I thought Hindman had written a whole paper about it).

Comment: I think Hindman's theorem is in *[Finite sums from sequences within cells of a partition of $N$](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(74)90023-5)*, Journal of Combinatorial Theory (A), 17, 1-11 (1974).

Comment: Some Hindman's personal recollections can be found in the paper Neil Hindman: *Algebra in the Stone-Cech compactification and its applications to Ramsey theory*, Scientiae Mathematicae Japonicae 62 (2005), 321-329. Preprint is freely available on the authors website: http://www.nhindman.us/research/jams.pdf